# ignoring the user's ~/.cshrc in CShell scripts, bash equivalent

Tags: bash

I have a `cshell` script with `-f` as argument to ignore the user's `~/.cshrc` file.

Is there a bash equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `bash` manpage:

- `--norc`: Do  not  read  and  execute the system wide initialization file /etc/bash.bashrc and the personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive.  This option is on by default  if  the shell is invoked as sh.
- `--noprofile`: Do  not  read either the system-wide startup file /etc/profile or any of the personal initializa‐tion files ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile.  By default,  bash  reads  these  files when it is invoked as a login shell.

If you want to keep using the system-wide rc file, but not the personal one, I imagine you can use the following and only name the system-wide one:

- `--rcfile file`: Execute  commands  from  file instead of the system wide initialization file /etc/bash.bashrc and the standard personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive.